# Strings in Keys becoming Integers?

Tags: php

I am wrote an array for all months in a year as follows:

```
$MNTH["01"] = "January";
$MNTH["02"] = "February";
$MNTH["03"] = "March";
$MNTH["04"] = "April";
$MNTH["05"] = "May";
$MNTH["06"] = "June";
$MNTH["07"] = "July";
$MNTH["08"] = "August";
$MNTH["09"] = "September";
$MNTH["10"] = "October";
$MNTH["11"] = "November";
$MNTH["12"] = "December";
```

When I do a variable dump on the keys of `$MNTH` with `var_dump(array_keys($MNTH))`,
I get:

```
array(12) {
 [0]=> string(2) "01"
 [1]=> string(2) "02"
 [2]=> string(2) "03"
 [3]=> string(2) "04"
 [4]=> string(2) "05"
 [5]=> string(2) "06"
 [6]=> string(2) "07"
 [7]=> string(2) "08"
 [8]=> string(2) "09"
 [9]=> int(10)
 [10]=> int(11)
 [11]=> int(12) }
```

I was expecting strings for the last three keys. How did it become integer? What should I do to correct this phenomenon?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Ahh, the wonders of dynamically types languages...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP converts numeric keys to integers at the time you create the array element. It isn't `array_keys` that is doing it. But there is a hack to get string numeric keys:

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->{"0"} = "zero";
$a = (array) $a;
var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["0"]=>
  string(4) "zero"
}
```

But you won't be able to access that key by subscript, so it's not very useful.

If you must have string keys, you'll need to prefix them with another non-numeric (or zero) character:

```
$MNTH["001"] = "January";
$MNTH["012"] = "December";
```

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> A key may be either an integer or a string. If a key is the standard representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such (i.e. "8" will be interpreted as 8, while "08" will be interpreted as "08"). Floats in key are truncated to integer. The indexed and associative array types are the same type in PHP, which can both contain integer and string indices.

Answer (score 0):

PHP determines the type of the variable based on context, so 10,11,12 is considered as integer.
If you want to force them to be string you can either cast to string like this

```
$MNTH[(string)"11"] = "November";
```

or concatenate an empty string.

```
$MNTH["11".""] = "November";
```

Comment: Both of those examples actually yield the same results.

Comment: Nope, i tried, your method doesn't work. Both still remains integer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do an associative array?

```
$MNTH = array(
         array("01" => "January"),array("02"=>"February"),array("03"=>"March"),
          ... snip ...
         array("12"=>"December")
             );
```

Comment: Why would I want to make it more complicated by introducing arrays within an array?

Comment: it just makes it easier to iterate over the data and output the months without resorting to hacks.